# PetoPoco ExecuteScalar - Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dotnetnuke, petapoco

I am working with DotNetNuke 7's DAL2 as outlined by Charles Nurse in his blog 
http://www.charlesnurse.com/Blog/tabid/226/EntryId/69/DAL-2-DataContext-Deep-Dive.aspx
and have come across an unexpected error when using ExecuteScalar.

My stored procedure fires and inserts to the database but overall the code errors with a 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.'. I have seen this error related to the data Reader though in my case I use DotNetNuke's integration of PetaPoco. any insight its greatly appreciated. Here is the code

```
public int AddLocation(string LocationType, string Name, string Description, string Address, string AreaCode, string Telephone, int Capacity, float Long, float Lat)
        {
            int id;
            using (IDataContext db = DataContext.Instance())
            {

                id = db.ExecuteScalar<int>(CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    "CP_AddLocation", LocationType, Name, Description, Address, AreaCode, Telephone, Capacity, Long, Lat);
            }
            return id;
        }
```

And my Stored Procedure. it works by itself and returns the newest Id. I should mention something I noticed and found odd is that if I declare a parameter as an output param ie @LocationId int OUTPUT then the addLocation() method does not work giving and error like this "Expected parameter @LocationId".

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CP_AddLocation]
 @locationType nvarchar(100),
 @name nvarchar(100),
 @description nvarchar(200),
 @address nvarchar(250),
 @areaCode nvarchar(50),
 @telephone nvarchar(50),
 @capacity int,
 @long float,
 @lat float

AS

DECLARE @geoCode geography
SET @geoCode = geography:: STGeomFromText('POINT (' + CAST(@long AS varchar) + ' ' + CAST(@lat AS varchar) + ')',4326);
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CP_Locations(
    LocationType,
    Name,
    Description,
    Address,
    AreaCode,
    Telephone,
    GeoCode,
    Capacity,
    Long,
    Lat)
    VALUES(
    @locationType,
    @name,
    @description,
    @address,
    @areaCode,
    @telephone,
    @geoCode,
    @capacity,
    @long,
    @lat)
END
declare @locationId int;
select @locationId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
return @locationId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute scalar requires the value to be selected as it gets the value from the first row and first column of the result set.

So just replace your last 3 lines of your Stored Procedure with

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And you will be set!

Answer (score 0):

I had to tinker to get a similar result. Here's what worked for me.

```
public static int Foo() 
{
    string query = "DECLARE @@return_value int; EXEC @@return_value = [foo].[dbo].[Proc_Name]; SELECT 'val' = @@return_value";

    int results = new int();

    using (var db = new PetaPoco.Database("ConnectionStringName"))
    {
        results = db.ExecuteScalar<int>(query, new object[] { });
    }

    return results;
}
```